# Установил пакет entity framework core и сломаля MySQL.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Решил перенести свои разработки на entity framework core. Потом решил что займусь этим потом и удалил из nuget entity framework core. Но после установки сломал что и так работало. Т.е. MySQL.Data.MySqlClient. Помогите вернуть все на место)))
Вот скрин ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста что я сделал и как лечить. И что сделать чтобы такого не происходило впредь.

Comment: попробуй эту ошибку вбить в гугл, думаю сразу найдешь решение

Comment: @AndreyFreiz допер без гугла спасибо))

Comment: Самый лучший совет как вернуть всё на место: использовать системы версионного контроля кода. Могли бы в два клика посмотреть содержимое на нужный момент, сравнить содержимое или откатиться к нужной версии. И я так понимаю, это как с бекапами: пока один раз данные не потеряешь -- не поймёшь, что это делать надо всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ссылках проекта удалил ссылку на MySql.Data оставил только MySqlConnector.